# How do I structure the import statement for this Python file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, python-import, discord.py

I have a project folder structure as below:

```
CHATNETBOT
    lib
        bot
            __init__.py
        cogs
            hub.py
        db
        utils
            modules
                config.py
    launcher.py
```

I am trying really hard to get the correct structure of an `import` statement in `hub.py` for `config.py`. I am currently on:

```
from ..utils.modules import config
```

This is a bot with several cogs, of which `hub.py` is one, and these are dynamically loaded in `__init__.py` using `Bot.load_extension` from `discord.py`. When my code tries to load `hub.py`, I get the following error:

```
ExtensionFailed("Extension 'lib.cogs.hub' raised an error: ValueError: attempted relative import beyond top-level package
```

I have tried several different structures for my `import` statement, but they all give me a "module not found" or the above error.

How should I structure my `import`?

Comment: Pretty sure you need an `__init__.py` in every subdirectory you intend to import.

Comment: @MarkCook As far as I can see, each subdirectory I want to import has an `__init__.py` file. The structure I gave in the question only shows directories and key files, not all files.